# How can I make multiple images fit in a container?

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images in a container and would like them to fit into one container but the problmem is that I can't change the width and the height as I'm currently making an app that makes it dynamic.

As you can see I put a red border for the container, the right border is missing.

This is what I got:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/ec67f4db463750c394c4e720acedf6b506b55b48_x1d-ii-sample-01-web.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
  <img src="https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG">
</div>
```

How can I make these images fit inside the red border?

Comment: no way.. you should add width:33.33%; or add div for three images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with `flex: 1` CSS property.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.container div {
  flex: 1;
}
.container img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
  
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/ec67f4db463750c394c4e720acedf6b506b55b48_x1d-ii-sample-01-web.jpg">
  </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would recommend doing this, you can keep all the images in one line, it's responsive, and calculated:

```css
.section {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
 .section .section-inner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1248px;
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers container */
  padding: 10px; /* this combined with the margin in the divs will make the margins appear consistent */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row; /* sort into rows */
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;

  background-color: rgba(255,100,100,0.25);
 }
  .section .section-inner div {
   width: calc((100% / 4) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   padding-top: calc((100% / 4) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
   margin: 10px; /* space between boxes */

   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
  }
   @media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .section .section-inner div {
     width: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
     padding-top: calc((100% / 2) - 20px); /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
    }
   }
   @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    .section .section-inner div {
     width: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
     padding-top: 100%; /* calculate width for maximum accuracy | minus margin */
    }
   }

   .image-one {
    background-image: url(https://www.fairtrade.org.uk/~/media/FairtradeUK/Media%20Centre/Flowers.jpg?h=397&la=en&mw=760&w=760);
   }
   .image-two {
    background-image: url(https://www.floraqueen.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Untitled-design-3-1.jpg);
   }
   .image-three {
    background-image: url(https://www.elimaysflowers.co.uk/assets/uploads/elimays1.jpg);
   }
   .image-four {
    background-image: url(https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/AsaMYX4F9WRNVTLsARRAsR-1920-80.jpg);
   }
```

```html
<section class="section">
 <div class="section-inner">
  <div class="image-one"></div>
  <div class="image-two"></div>
  <div class="image-three"></div>
  <div class="image-four"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

If you want them to keep scaling and not go responsive, remove the responsive CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should add like this

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.container div{
    width:33.33%;
}

.container img {
    max-width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/ec67f4db463750c394c4e720acedf6b506b55b48_x1d-ii-sample-01-web.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 0px;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/ec67f4db463750c394c4e720acedf6b506b55b48_x1d-ii-sample-01-web.jpg">
  <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg">
  <img src="https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG">
</div>
```

Comment: Using `float` is a bad practice when there are better alternatives available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way.

```css
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 1170px;
        border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://cdn.hasselblad.com/ec67f4db463750c394c4e720acedf6b506b55b48_x1d-ii-sample-01-web.jpg"  width="304" height="236">
  <img src="https://4.img-dpreview.com/files/p/E~TS590x0~articles/3925134721/0266554465.jpeg" width="304" height="236">
  <img src="https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/digital_cameras/x/fujifilm_x20/sample_images/img/index/ff_x20_008.JPG"  width="304" height="236">
</div>
```